# Custom Geo location on xamarin forms

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms, geolocation, coordinates, custom-renderer

Is there anyway to customize the geolocator to show the custom co-ordinate we are given, using customrenderer or anything.

Whenever geolocation button clicked it should move to the custom co-ordinate and zoom level we given. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
void MoveToRegion(Position position) {
     Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                                               Map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(position, Distance.FromKilometers(1)));
                                          });
}
```

Comment: problem is when this method executes it didn't update or refresh the custom map i have binded.

Comment: If you use bindings then you can use Map property VisibleRegion={Bindibg VisibleRegion}